# How do i check with a MongoDB query if a property in an object exists?

Tags: mongodb

I'm building a simple query for my MongoDB Collection. The model looks like this:

```
{
    a: [],
    user: {
        email: String,
        name: String,
        surname: String
    }
}
```

What I need to get from the query are all the documents that have 'a' as non-empty array and the 'user.email' set. My query is:

```
Document.find({
        a: {
            $exists: true,
            $not: {
                $size: 0
            }
        },
        user: {
            $exists: true,
            'email': {
                $exists: true
            }
        }
    })
```

The problem is when i perform the query, my server returns a 500 Error saying:

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "MongoError",
        "message": "unknown operator: email",
        "waitedMS": 0,
        "ok": 0,
        "errmsg": "unknown operator: email",
        "code": 2
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way you structured your query, the MongoDB engine tries parsing the `email` keyword as an operator on the `user` field.

If you want to check if a nested attribute is defined on a document, you can use the dot notation:

```
Document.find({
        a: {
            $exists: true,
            $not: {
                $size: 0
            }
        },
        "user.email": {
            $exists: true
        }
    })
```